# Overload puppet default parameter in module

Tags: puppet

I want to use my own Jenkins plugin server to source plugins from. I'm using the puppet-jenkins module, but I can't seem to change the default plugin host value

The [code on github](https://github.com/jenkinsci/puppet-jenkins) has this in `manifests/params`:

```
class jenkins::params {
    ..
    $default_plugins_host  = 'https://updates.jenkins-ci.org'
    ..
}
```

So when I use this class, if I say:

```
class { 'jenkins': 
     default_plugins_host => "https://myhost.local"
}
```

I get `Puppet (err): Invalid parameter`

Or, if I try to define the value using capscase:

```
Jenkins::Params { 
     default_plugins_host => "https://specificallybrokenhost.com"
}
```

it isn't used by puppet. I tested this by giving it a plugin host that didn't exist, expecting the plugin installation to fail; but it was able to get plugins successfully (my assumption is that it still used jenkins-ci.org)

I was able to get this working by coping the entire module locally within `library-jenkins/puppet-jenkins` and changing the value, but i'd prefer not to have to resort to that

I'm using puppet-librarian and Puppet 3.3, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the params.pp file stores private variables. This cannot be overridden.

Looking over the module is appears you can change the url from lines 67-82 of plugin.pp

```
if $version {
  $plugins_host = $update_url ? {
    undef   => $::jenkins::default_plugins_host,
    default => $update_url,
  }
 $base_url = "${plugins_host}/download/plugins/${name}/${version}/"
 $search   = "^${name} ${version}$"
}
else {
  $plugins_host = $update_url ? {
    undef   => $::jenkins::default_plugins_host,
    default => $update_url,
  }
  $base_url = "${plugins_host}/latest/"
  $search   = "${name} "
}
```

$plugins_host will use update_url if it's defined instead of default_plugins_host. if you make a default on the plugin define type you can change the default_plugins_host to update_url like so;

```
Jenkins::Plugin {
  source_url => 'mycompany.jenkins.com',
}
```

I haven't tested this myself. So, let me know if it works.

Comment: This works! I updated the last code snippet to use the correct variable name, but after that change, this saw me right. I didn't know that `params.pp` was private space :(